# The MVT suffers from External fragmentation.

Tags: operating-system

So the question is:

The MVT suffers from External fragmentation. This problem has 3 solutions, name the solution methods.

My problem is that I have no idea what MVT is. A Google search didn't yield and relevant results... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Multiprogramming with variable number of tasks

Linked allocation and indexed allocation solves external fragmentation. 3rd? I dont know, sorry.

-Chris